# SQL ORDER BY Doubts

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
|---------------------     |------------------           |
|      AttendanceCode      |     AttendanceDescription   |
|---------------------     |------------------           |
|          MC              |         Medical Leave       |
|---------------------     |------------------           |
|         NAPFA            |            NAPFA            |
|---------------------     |------------------           |
|        Present           |            Present          |
|---------------------     |------------------           |
```

I'm using SQL Server 2014. I have a table with two columns, AttendanceCode and AttendanceDescription and I'm using a dropdownlist to display the AttendanceDescription. I would like the dropdownlist order to display "Present" first. I tried using this query:

```
SELECT AttendanceCode, AttendanceDescription
FROM journalattendancestatus
ORDER BY (CASE AttendanceDescription WHEN 'P' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AttendanceDescription
```

And this

```
SELECT AttendanceCode, AttendanceDescription
FROM journalattendancestatus
ORDER BY CASE WHEN AttendanceDescription = 'Present' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
         AttendanceDescription";
```

But none of them work. I've also tried to change it to AttendanceCode where 'P' represent 'Present'.

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result!

Comment: Added sample table data

Comment: I think your case isn't actually picking up the key 'present' - is it definitely spelled right etc - try putting CASE WHEN AttendanceDescription = 'Present' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS Test in your list of fields and see that it comes up as 1 or 2when you expect it to - your idea is definitely right!

Comment: I'm sure the second one is correct for getting 'Present' to the top of the list, there may be some glitch with the actual text, padding, etc

Comment: why you added AttendanceDescription at last in ORDER BY CASE WHEN AttendanceDescription = 'Present' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
         AttendanceDescription"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AttendanceDescription` column only once in `ORDER BY` clause

```
SELECT AttendanceCode, AttendanceDescription
FROM journalattendancestatus
ORDER BY CASE WHEN AttendanceCode = 'Present' THEN 1  
              WHEN AttendanceCode = 'MC'      THEN 2  
              WHEN AttendanceCode = 'NAPFA'   THEN 3 
          END
```

Comment: Hi, the query still doesn't display Present as the default choice. Thanks

Comment: Added sample table data

Comment: the order is Medical Certificate, NAPFA then pressent

Comment: Hi, it seems like the order is correct, but the default value is still Medical Certificate. Is it possible to change it to Present?

Answer (score 0):

Order by is simply to sort your data by a column.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE AGE=18 ORDER BY NAME DESC
```

That will take your SQL and order it in reverse alphabetical order.

What exactly are you trying to do? I might be able to give you a solution to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I would like the Present to be display as default in the dropdownlist. Right now there are 4 to 5 data, such as Present, Medical Leave.

Comment: Added sample table data

Answer (score 0):

for this query nulls will come first..

```
ORDER BY (CASE AttendanceDescription WHEN 'P' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AttendanceDescription
```

Change it to

```
WHEN 'P' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
```

second query is almost close..

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN AttendanceDescription = 'Present' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
         AttendanceDescription";
```

But when 1 has ties it again falls back to AttendanceDescription to break ties,so in this case it can be any thing..so remove that

Comment: Hi i tried this ORDER BY CASE WHEN 'Present' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END    and this ORDER BY CASE WHEN 'P' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END. Both doesn't work.

Comment: Added sample table data

Answer (score 0):

Your second query is working. It has syntax error. I have removed ',' near END statement and double quotes at the end of query.

```
SELECT AttendanceCode, AttendanceDescription
FROM journalattendancestatus
ORDER BY CASE WHEN AttendanceDescription = 'Present' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
         AttendanceDescription;
```

In first query you are searching for a letter 'P' which is not present in your column. You can use like here.

```
ORDER BY (CASE when AttendanceDescription like 'Pre%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AttendanceDescription
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best option but just an idea:

```
SELECT AttendanceCode, AttendanceDescription, 1 AS OrderIndex 
FROM journalattendancestatus
WHERE AttendanceDescription = 'P' 
UNION
SELECT AttendanceCode, AttendanceDescription, 2 AS OrderIndex 
FROM journalattendancestatus
WHERE AttendanceDescription != 'P' 
ORDER BY OrderIndex, AttendanceCode, AttendanceDescription
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me in HANA

```
SELECT AttendanceCode, AttendanceDescription
FROM journalattendancestatus
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN AttendanceDescription= 'Present' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @flttaxrate float
declare @fltArea float
declare @fltbasetax float

set @fltArea=139.3
set @flttaxrate=50

set @fltbasetax=@fltArea*@flttaxrate
select @fltbasetax
select ceiling(@fltbasetax)
```

please check the output  select @fltbasetax,  select ceiling(@fltbasetax)